# Перезагружается страница при отправке формы

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii2

Есть обычная форма, из которой при submit'е, берутся: `url`, `action`, серелизованые данные и делается ajax запрос

```
<form class="dynamic-form ajaxform modal-after-submit" action="/form/order-call-simple" method="post" data-after-modal="button[href=&quot;#wi-popup2&quot;]">

  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf-frontend" value="_kqgpOBZWj5LfdylhccB0nUrhlCSftWer04-vyj_vlGRJc3WkGwVdyQprtfQrXS9Kn-2B806ksnfY0bZUpjzMg==" />

  <input class="telephone-mask" name="2" maxlength="19" placeholder="( ___ )   ___-__-__" required="true" />

  <input type="checkbox" class="form-control checkbox2" id="dynamicForm_w0_checkbox" required="" checked="" />
  <label for="dynamicForm_w0_checkbox">Ознакомлен и согласен с <a href="/politika-sbora-informacii/">политикой сбора информации</a></label>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="" value="Заказать" />
</form>
```

Отправка:

```
   $('form.ajaxform').on('submit', function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       event.stopImmediatePropagation();

       var form = $(this);

       $.ajax({
           url: form.attr('action'),
           method: form.attr('method'),
           data: form.serialize(),
           success: function (response) {
              console.log('Форма отправилась');
           },
           error: function (error) {
              // Перед перезагрузкой, прелетает ошибка 
               console.log(error);
           }
       });
   });
```

Проблема в том, что сразу после ajax запроса, браузер делает переход по тому урлу, на который был отправлен запрос.
Еще, после запроса, в error callback прилетает какая-та ошибка такого вида: `{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}` - это вроде объект, но он не раскрывается в консоли (не знаю что это). Также, в консоли выводится предупреждение - `VM4682 yii.js:360 Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "site.loc/form/order-call-simple"`.

На backend'е, данные отправляются очень незамысловато

```
class FormController extends BaseController
{
    public $enableCsrfValidation = false;

    public function actionOrderCallSimple()
    {
        //TODO: Implement this method
        return $this->asJson(['success' => true]);
    }
}
```

В чем может быть проблема? `event.preventDefault()` - не причем, он работает если не отправлять запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в отсутствии слеша в конце url'a, т.е. url должен был выглядеть так: `/form/order-call-simple/`.
По этой причине, браузер получал от сервера статус-код: `302` и делал редирект на тот же url, только уже со слешем на конце.

Answer (score 1):

> VM4682 yii.js:360 Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "site.loc/form/order-call-simple"

это означает, что твой обработчик возвращает тебе массив. Добавь в js

```
dataType:"json",
```

по поводу перехода, попробуй в success и error обработчики ajax добавить

```
return false;
```

Comment: а так же попробуй надеть деревянные наушники и помахать палочками на взлетной полосе - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82

Comment: @Igor не понял сарказма. Если знаешь ответ или можешь помочь, пиши. Своим таким сарказмом показываешь свой уровень интеллекта, что не выше у школоло с ЧСВ овер 9000. Или молчи...

Comment: извините, ошибся - "также" в данном случае надо писать слитно

Comment: может стоит поменять `type="submit"` на `type="button"` `input-У`

Comment: @Air `event.preventDefault();` это и так компенсирует. Подозреваю, что дело в `yii`, и что есть другие обработчики `submit`-a.

Comment: @Igor, согласен...

Answer (score 1):

Если версия Yii2 свежайшая, то стоит перехватывать событие beforeSubmit. Т.к. форма реализована без использования ActiveForm (или это исходник формы из инспектора?), то скорее всего такого события не наступит.

Чтобы запретить дефолтную отправку формы, необходимо вернуть false. Стандартно так:

```
$('form.ajaxform').on('submit', function (event) {
    // ваш код для обработки данных без превентов и пропогатионов
    // отправка данных на сервер
    return false; // это остановит стандартную отправку формы браузером
});
```

Необходимо обратить внимание на то, что return false следует разместить в самом конце, чтобы вернуть сразу, после нажатия кнопки сабмита. Блок с ajax выполнится чуть позже, потому что ему надо еще подождать ответа от сервера. Ретурны из блока ajax не изменят ситуацию.

Comment: Форма из инспектора, но создается с помощью Html::beginForm() и Html::endForm() (создается в том виде, в котором я её скопировал из испектора).  `return false` - не помог

Comment: обработчик `beforeSubmit` на это форму тоже не реагирует, видимо проблема не в этом.

Comment: ActiveForm генерирует событие beforeSubmit, из-за Html::beginForm() наверно такое событие не возникает. Где return расположен?

Comment: Расположен в конце

Comment: Я сейчас просмотрел список запросов которые отправляются. Почему-то, после ajax запроса, браузер делает еще один "обычный" запрос, по этому урлу и в ответ получает 302

Comment: Надо поэтапно пробовать. Из js (где событие сабмита) убрать весь код и добавить вывод в консоль, а в конце return false. При этом форма не должна отправится. Если отправляется, возможно ее отправляет еще что-то.